# calling functions in C

Tags: c, x86, x86-64, compiler-optimization

My question is particulary to function calls in C. So, either we can call functions normally or through function pointers. When your interface remainas the same but with different implementations, function pointers are used, but even if you have a single implementation having function pointers can improve the readabilty of the code.

So, what are the benefits of having static calls rather than dynamic function pointers. The call will obviously be implemented in 2 instructions as the address of the function needs to be fetched, but return will take equal cycles. I just want to understand, how can if at all processor and compiler optimize static calls over dynamic functions pointers?

Thanks,

Comment: You state that using function pointers is more readable than normal function calls, would you mind elaborating why you think that?

Comment: "...even if you have a single implementation having function pointers can improve the readabilty of the code...". I don't see how. What exactly do you mean by this?

Answer (score 3):

Calling a function through a pointer will in most cases result in the compiler not being able to inline the call (if the compiler has determined that it would be beneficial to do so.) In some cases, the compiler is even able to determine the result of a function call at compile time, and thus optimize-away the whole code of the function. Function pointers also prevent this from happening.

That doesn't mean that the impact will be noticeable in any way that actually matters though. The only way to determine that, is to go and benchmark/profile your code.

However, I don't see how function pointers would be able to provide better code readability. You might want to give an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, direct call allows way more optimization to the compiler.

If there is really only one implementation and compiler can see it [*], it can optimize and do exactly as with direct call. But it of course depends on how smart the compiler is and what optimization options you use.

[*] i.e. if the pointer value is known in compile time; i.e. if it is 'static' variable, its address never passed outside the compilation unit, etc.